# How to get Image Info from UploadCare in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier, uploadcare

In Zapier, using an UploadCare trigger, I'm trying to get image height and width data using a Code by Zapier step (JavaScript).

[Screenshot of "Run Javascript" template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omVP2.jpg)

The input data is *Data Image Info*, and the code is as follows:

```
return {info: inputData.info};
```

The problem is that the test output returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Chad!

We fixed our Zap and it is ready to use!
Here is setup: ["Run javascript template"](https://ucarecdn.com/dc257d68-66a1-405d-b30e-8fff1d66a930/ScreenShot20171026at152253.png)

Comment: Awesome!  Will this still return height and width info if the uploaded image does NOT have EXIF data?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uploaded file must be an image
2. Uploaded image file must have metadata with image dimensions information(EXIF)

It seems that Zapier(or Zapier <-> Uploadcare integration) lost `image_info` file field. We certainly send that field from Uploadcare to Zapier.

We will inspect that problem and will message you about results.

Thank you.